# How to list different terms with their nodes in one view?

Tags: 8

Now I had a question, is it possible to build a view which can display different terms with multiple content on drupal 8?

For example,

Term 1

- node 1
- node 2
- node 3

Term 2

- node 2
- node 4
- node 6

Term 3

- node 5
- node 7
- node 8

Can someone help me out?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve you requirement by below steps:

1. Create view at **/admin/structure/views**
2. Now add fields which you want to display.
3. Click on **Settings** under FORMAT section.

[image]

4. Now add your taxonomy field as **Grouping Field**

[image]